# Why won't bundle install railties 3.2.3 on my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, bundler, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails 3.2.2 has been working fine in both my development environment, and on my server.

I'm trying to upgrade to 3.2.3 by changing:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
```

to

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
```

then running:

```
bundle update
bundle
```

All goes well until I try to deploy to my server.  During the deploy, I get this message:

```
An error occured while installing railties (3.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install railties -v '3.2.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have logged into the server and ran the gem install railties -v '3.2.3' command and it works without problems.  But the deploy always fails in the same way.

I've tried to delete the cache directory as shown [here](http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/2010/11/rails-fixing-bundle-no-metadata-found-issues/), but I'm not sure I'm doing that correctly.  I'm using rvm on the server and my development environment.

Can anybody help point me in a direction on this?

Here's my deploy.rb file:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
require "rvm/capistrano"                  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.

set :application, "teamsite"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:user/teamsite.git"
set :deploy_to, "/home/website.com/rails/application/"
set :user, "website.com"
set :scm, :git
set :use_sudo, false
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :branch, "master"
set :scm_verbose, true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

task :staging do
  role :web, "staging.website.com"
  role :app, "staging.website.com"
  role :db,  "staging.website.com", :primary => true
end

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
      if capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run %Q{cd #{latest_release} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{asset_env} assets:precompile}
      else
        logger.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end
  end
end

namespace :customs  do
  task :create_symlink, :roles => :app do
    run <<-CMD
      ln -nfs #{shared_path}/files #{release_path}/files
    CMD

    run <<-CMD
      ln -nfs #{shared_path}/drawings #{release_path}/drawings
    CMD

    run <<-CMD
      ln -nfs #{shared_path}/photos #{release_path}/photos
    CMD
  end
end

after "deploy:create_symlink","customs:create_symlink"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
```

**Update**

I was able to finally fix this by deploying to a different user.  But the question still remains:  How would I clear out the gem cache for the old user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
gem pristine --all --no-extensions
```

to reinstall all your gems from scratch. If you're using passenger on your host, you will need to find out where that gem cache directory is really at. Look at the .bashrc for GEM_PATH value, mine on Dreamhost is:

```
export GEM_PATH="$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
```

Or if you're using RVM on your server, that path is likely to the current version rvm is using.